# Floor division with negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x, division, integer-division

The expression `6 // 4` yields `1`, where floor division produces the whole number after dividing a number.

But with a negative number, why does `-6 // 4` return `-2`?

Comment: Because that is floor division. `-2 < -6/4 <  -1`

Comment: Pretty weird question, you give the answer yourself

Comment: Because the result of the division is *always floored*. Flooring goes down, not up.

Comment: `-6/4 = -1.5` round that down and you have `-2`

Comment: Hence `floor`, not `ceiling`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `//` operator explicitly *floors* the result. Quoting the [*Binary arithmetic operations* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

Flooring is not the same thing as rounding to 0; flooring always moves to the *lower integer value*. See the [`math.floor()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor):

> Return the floor of *x*, the largest integer less than or equal to *x*.

For `-6 // 4`, first the result of `-6 / 4` is calculated, so `-1.5`. Flooring then moves to the lower integer value, so `-2`.

If you want to round towards zero instead, you'll have to do so explicitly; you could do this with the `int()` function on true division:

```
>>> int(-6 / 4)
-1
```

`int()` removes the decimal portion, so always rounds towards zero instead.

Comment: this was a good answer for mentioning `int()`

Answer (score 5):

Floor division will also round down to the next lowest number, not the next lowest absolute value.

`6 // 4 = 1.5`, which rounds down to 1, and up to 2.

`-6 // 4 = -1.5`, which rounds down to -2, and up to -1.

Answer (score 5):

A useful way to understand why floor division `//` yields the results it does for negative values is to consider that it complements the modulo, or remainder, `%` operator, which in Python is defined to always return a non-negative number.

```
5/3  is equivalent to 1 remainder 2
```

i.e.

```
5//3 = 1
5%3 = 2
```

But

```
-5/3 = -2
-5%3 = 1
```

Or

```
-2 + 1/3rd which is -1.6667 (ish)
```

It can seem strange, but it ensures results such as
`-2,-2,-2,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3`  etc. when generating sequences.

Answer (score 3):

`//` in Python is a "floor division" operator. That means that the result of such division is the floor of the result of regular division (performed with / operator).

The floor of the given number is the biggest integer smaller than the this number. For example

```
7 / 2 = 3.5 so 7 // 2 = floor of 3.5 = 3.
```

For negative numbers it is less intuitive: `-7 / 2 = -3.5,` so `-7 // 2 = floor of -3.5 = -4`. Similarly `-1 // 10 = floor of -0.1 = -1.`

`//` is defined to do the same thing as `math.floor()`: return the largest integer value less than or equal to the floating-point result. `Zero is not less than or equal to -0.1.`